# how to find the time gap between action up and action down event in android

Tags: android, events, gesture

i have following code...

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {

    //here i want to know the  time of touch

    switch (me.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { }  
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { }
       -
       -
       -
   }
  }
```

Any Idea?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Could you try to explain more in your question. Use a timer of some sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is pretty simple

```
public yourClass{
    long down;    
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
        //you don't need here the difference because it might be a down action!
        //you need the difference when the up action occurs
        switch (me.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                down = System.currentTimeMillis();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //this is the time in milliseconds
                long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - down; 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely you mean "-down", not "-long"

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to measure the time between the two events. This is very simple. All you need is to find an API method which returns the current time. In this case android.os.SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() or .uptimeMillis() should serve you ([android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html)).
When the first event occurs, you save the current time in a variable. On the second event you just calculate the difference between the current time and the value you stored before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

to capture the times on each event